# How to retrieve an Element from point with C

Tags: c, winapi, com, ui-automation

I have the following code to retrieve the element at particular positon at desktop:

```
#include "UiAutomationclient.h"

IUIAutomation *pAutomation = NULL;
IUIAutomationElement *element = NULL;

CoInitialize(NULL);
      
EXTERN_C const CLSID CLSID_CUIAutomation;
EXTERN_C const IID IID_IUIAutomation;

HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(&CLSID_CUIAutomation,NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,&IID_IUIAutomation,(void**)&pAutomation);
if(SUCCEEDED(hr)){
  GetCursorPos(&pt);
  hr = pAutomation->ElementFromPoint(pt,&element);
  if(SUCCEEDED(hr) && element != NULL){

  }
  pAutomation->Release();
}
CoUninitialize();
```

I am getting the following errors after compilation:

```
'ElementFromPoint': is not a member of 'IUIAutomation'
'Release': is not a member of 'IUIAutomation'
```

I am stuck at this point because I am doing what the documentation says. Tks in advance if someone can help me with those errors in C.

Comment: you need to use C++ to be able to use functions in structs/classes

Comment: @caelras: Not true; it's perfectly possible to store a function pointer in a struct in C and call it using exactly the syntax the OP's code is using. Whether or not that's how the library is designed to work is not something I can say, since I know absolutely nothing about it.

Comment: @caelras tks for your prompt answer. I am very new on those topics. How should I include in my code to use those functions?. And also how did you know that we need to use C++? I wanted to know to avoid those questions in the future. Tks again for your time.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen, Do you know how to do it?. Tks for helping me out by the way

Comment: It would help if you gave us a link to "what the documentation says" so we could check it ourselves. But it does seem plausible that you may be trying to use C++ example code in a C program.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen.... I am following the documention which is included on Microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/uiautomationclient/nf-uiautomationclient-iuiautomation-elementfrompoint

Comment: IF `IUIAutomation` is indeed designed to support both C and C++ clients, and you're really doing this from C, you probably need to drive through the `lpVtbl` member (or similar) of aIUIAutomation. I.e. `pAutomation->lpVtbl->ElementFromPoint(pt,&element);` The vtable of COM interfaces is setup a little strange in C programs, but it is probably something similar to that.

Comment: @sergioMoreno C++ is an extended version of C, It was originally called "C with classes". Classes allow you to define your own types. You make an instance of a class like this "ClassName obj;"

Comment: @sergioMoreno: Well, it says "C++" at the top of the code example on that page, so no, you probably can't just copy-paste those code examples into a C project without making any changes. Is there some specific reason why you want to do this in plain C?

Comment: @sergioMoreno continuing what I mentioned earlier, you could also use the macros traditionally provided in C-compatible COM headers. For that member it would be something along the lines of `IUIAutomation_ElementFromPoint(pAutomation, pt, &element);` . Chances are you're going to run into a similar issue with your `Release` invoke, which in C should be something like `IUnknown_Release(pAutomation);`

Comment: @IlmariKaronen, because I took a plain C library and I am adding some extra functionalities that I require for my project. That is why I decided to keep with plain C.

Comment: @WhozCraig Tks for your help. I replaced on my current code and I am getting the following warning: 'IUIAutomation_ElementFromPoint' undefined; assuming extern returning int. This is something that I should care about it?. Tks anyway for your help I am learning a lot

Comment: @sergioMoreno Yes you should care about it. You need to define `COBJMACROS` before including COM headers. In your case, you should probably just put it in the precompiled header driver (the header you base your pch from if you use one), or directly on the preprocessor configuration.

Comment: @WhozCraig amazing it works. I am reading now about macros to understand everything. Tks for introducing me in this topic and for your time to find a solution. I wish all the best.

Comment: @WhozCraig One question that I am curious about. How do you identify that I have to define this particular COBJMACROS? Any website that I can use for this purpose or documentation to find it. Tks

Comment: @sergioMoreno It's just an old-school COM knowledge thing. Almost no one ever actually drove COM in C, but if you played by the rules, used MS's macros religiously, and stuck with their odd formats, you wouldn't stop someone if the needed to. I literally just remembered it out of the blue (been at this a long, *long* time). If you think being a *client* in C to an inproc COM library is odd, be glad you're not *authoring* a COM lib in C. "Odd" doesn't really do justice in describing it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222818/discussion-between-sergiomoreno-and-whozcraig).

Comment: Using COM from C is indeed rare. Accessing COM through its C-compatible interface, on the other hand, is very, *very* common. It's ultimately the reason why COM can be language-agnostic.

Comment: @IInspectable Tks for your advice, where could I find information about its C-compatible interface to do it in a common way?. I mean I do not have enough experience and I would like to find a place to start doing the things how it should be done.

Answer (score 0):

Using COM form C is more verbose than from C++, but there are no fundamental differences.

Given call in C++

```
HRESULT hr = com_interface->method( arguments );
```

conversion to C looks as

```
HRESULT hr = com_interface->lpVtbl->method( com_interface, arguments );
```

Just put `->lpVtbl->` instead of `->` between interface pointer and method name, then repeat interface pointer as first argument.

In C++

```
hr = pAutomation->ElementFromPoint(pt,&element);
...
pAutomation->Release();
```

in C

```
hr = pAutomation->lpVtbl->ElementFromPoint(pAutomation,pt,&element);
...
pAutomation->lpVtbl->Release(pAutomation);
```